# What is the correct term to use here in this context?

Tags: functions, terminology

Say I have function, $y = e^{2x+1}$ so is it correct to say,

1. $x$ is the independent variable of the function.
2. $ 2x + 1$ is the *argument* of the function.

I'm getting confused between independent variable and argument.

Can anyone highlight some distinguishing points that can clear my confusion?

Thanks!

Comment: $x$ is the [argument (also known as : independent variable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_a_function) of the function $2x+1$. But $x$ is also the argument of the [composed function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) $e^{2x+1}$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_a_function

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I just read that, I had the confusion because my teacher refers to $2x+1$ as argument, anyway then what term should I use to refer to whatever is inside $ {.}$ of $e^{.} $ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What is the difference between the last two sentences you said. (I'm dumb please forgive me :) )

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $e^5$ umm so where are you going with this?

Comment: A function is a box: filling the "entry slot" with an input, the box returns an output. The input is the *argument* and the output is the *value*. The so-called "independent variable" is the argument and the argument-place (the "entry slot") is denoted usually with $x$. Having said that if we input $2$ and the function returns $5$, we have to conclude that $x$ is the argument of $e^{2x+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=e^{2x+1}$ , then $x$ is the  independent variable of $f$ and $x$ is the argument in $f$.

Comment: So basically you're saying, argument and independent variable are one and same thing?

Comment: Yes, they are one and same thing.

Comment: then what term should I use to refer to whatever is inside $ {.}$ of $e^{.} $ ?